# subquery script SQL / MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am doing an academic assignment and I am receiving error code 1111 Invalid Use of Group function. Can any one explain / show me how to fix this error?

task: Using a subquery display the client id and last name for each client who has at least one animal that is not a reptile.

```
SELECT vt_clients.cl_id , vt_clients.cl_name_last 
FROM vt_clients 
WHERE vt_clients.cl_id NOT IN(SELECT an.cl_id 
FROM vt_animals an WHERE an_type IN('snake', 'lizard', 'turtle') AND COUNT(an_type) > 1);
```

[table chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/619ZK.png)

Comment: `Count()` or other aggregation functions cannot be used inside the `WHERE` clause. What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: In where clause you cant have aggregate function like count(an_type) use group by with having count() something like that since your query is working row by row fir retrieval and theres no group at the same time to aggregate suddenly in where clause

Comment: My requested task is to Display the client id and last name for each client who has at least one animal that is not a reptile while using subquery. @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT vt_clients.cl_id , vt_clients.cl_name_last 
FROM vt_clients 
WHERE not exists
(SELECT 1  
FROM vt_animals an WHERE an.cl_id=vt_clients.cl_id and an_type IN('snake', 'lizard', 'turtle') 
having COUNT(an_type) >= 1
)
```

Comment: Can you explain the significance of using 'SELECT 1' ?

Comment: `having COUNT(an_type) >= 1` is really unnecessary here, because filtering is done on `an_type`. Also, usage of `Having` without `GROUP BY` is not recommended and most likely will throw error in stricter mode.

Comment: @Ed_, selecting 1 instead of column names is better in terms of performance - but you can select column name also

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya how would you have scripted the response?

Comment: @Ed_ It does not matter whether you use `select 1` , `select *` or `select any column name`. "Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: @Ed_ also, in order to get a better and *more efficient quey* from the **larger community**, you should read this link once: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308  :-)

Comment: Thank you Madhur :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `exists`:

```
SELECT c.cl_id , c.cl_name_last 
FROM vt_clients c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM vt_animals a
              WHERE c.cl_id = c.cl_id AND
                    a.an_type NOT IN ('snake', 'lizard', 'turtle')
            );
```

You just need the existence of one non-reptilian animal, so there is no need for `count()`.